# org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer.poll blocks for a long time

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm still quite new to kafka. In some helper project(for debugging) we use directly `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer` and we're calling `poll` in loop. The problem is, that we might connect to server which is on the other part of the globe. When we do so, it seems, that execution is blocked for second or so, and then all of polled data are processed in no time, and then waiting again.

I know I might tune consumer to fetch at least say 5M of data, but I don't think this is correct. Is there principally better approach in this situation? The line shouldn't be extra slow, but roundtrips over a lot of time zones is. I'm not sure if reactive approach will help us, as there are (not sure if in kafka, but generally) also these backpressure `request` calls. But if it's possible to somehow find out "sending speed" which is acceptable for consumer(similarly like TCP protocol updates it's congestion window), we might utilitize connection much better.

Please give me some hints what to use / recommend some reading (specific part).

Comment: Can you provide the consumer config? Also, how long have you set the poll timeout to?

Comment: Consumer config was in it's default values. Then I tried to set: 

`props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, 1024*1024*40);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, 1024*1024*60);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 1000*10);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 1000*10);`

but it's the same — 6s waiting, then in ~250ms it will produce ~6MB of data, 6s waiting.

In loop I call: `consumer.poll(Duration.of(500, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));` for responsiveness, but I changed it to 10s and behavior is stil lthe same.

Comment: ... my network is way not fully utilitized, I cannot say that for the whole network from my PC to customers kafka server, as most of devices/servers/vpn are not accessible in any way to me to do some checking. However it seems weird to me, that data aren't flowing at ± constant speed, or with some small delay. Yes, the shortest distance between datacenters will be ~10kkm, but estimated RTT latency is in hundreds of ms. So I don't get it what can be attributing to said behavior.